# How to detect that a TextField is focused when implementing custom TextFieldStyle in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, textfield, textfieldstyle

I am implementing a custom TextFieldStyle like follow:

```
struct CustomTextFieldStyle: TextFieldStyle {
  func _body(configuration: TextField<Self._Label>) -> some View {
    configuration
      .foregroundColor(Color.black)
  }
}
```

However, I would like to change the foreground color when the text field is "focused". I tried this:

```
struct CustomTextFieldStyle: TextFieldStyle {

  @Environment(\.isFocused) private var isFocused

  func _body(configuration: TextField<Self._Label>) -> some View {
    configuration
      .foregroundColor(isFocused ? Color.blue : Color.black)
  }
}
```

but that does not seem to work as isFocused is always false.

Anyone has a hint of how to detect when a textfield is focused? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your text field style, use a @FocusState Boolean, bind that to the text field you’re wrapping and then adjust your formatting based on its value:

```swift
struct CustomTextFieldStyle: TextFieldStyle {
    @FocusState var isFocused: Bool

    func _body(configuration: TextField<Self._Label>) -> some View {
        configuration
            .focused($isFocused)
            .foregroundColor(isFocused ? .blue : .black)
    }
}
```